# What If I train with Multiple Copies of same data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, stochastic-gradient-descent, pre-training

I am training a char-rnn to yield some nice generative output. Can I make it memorize context by using the same copies of data in training, multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeated use of the same data in fitting just gives that data too much weight.  It provides a false indication of the "true" sample size and hence makes the variance of parameter estimates improperly small.

Answer (score 2):

This is another question which addresses the same point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705166/repeating-training-with-the-same-data-set

You are risking over-fitting but if you add noise as suggested in the answer it could help you.

Comment: Also, is overfitting the same as memorizing the training data. I  understand the term overfitting, but intuitively it is actually memorizing data instead of generalizing right?

Comment: Yes, you start learning each case in training, and not generalizing